# Using JQuery how do I get the vertical space above an element on the page?

Tags: jquery

I have an element on a page about 150 pixels down the screen. This is different in different browsers so I want to auto scroll the page to the top of an element that is about 150 pixels down the page. How do I determine what the location of that element relative to the top of the page?

I am trying this but it isn't working. offset() is returning null.

```
var positionOfLiveMapTop = $(mapElem).offset().top;
```

Comment: If `.offset()` returns null then the element cannot be found on the page, or is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.scrollTo(0, $(mapElem).offset().top);
```

Make sure that mapElem is set. Your problem is most likely that it's not global and is undefined in the context you're using it in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you executing your script after the DOM content has loaded?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var positionOfLiveMapTop = $(mapElem).offset().top;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jose,
Unless you're looking for the animation associated with the scrollTo() function, this can be achieved without javascript by ulitizing the bookmark feature of anchors.

```
<a name="bookmark">Scroll to Here</a>
<a href="#bookmark">From Here</a>
```